# How can I verify that a script that works in a SQL editor (DBeaver) will not run into syntax errors in Liquibase?

Tags: postgresql, liquibase

Running into this constantly over the past few days:

1. edit a file in DBeaver
2. execute the code
3. rollback the change (truncate/drop etc)
4. run the change with Liquibase

Result: some variation on "syntax error" or "unterminated string constant" or "Unterminated dollar quote". But the scripts run fine in the SQL tool! How can I double check that a SQL script is "Liquibase compatible" or something like that before I go through the trouble of running it in Liquibase? Note: our liquibase is running in the cloud, so getting results out of it takes a few minutes because the logs need to catch up. Even if they are run locally it's still tedious to try and track down the issues. I'm using json configs if that matters.

Comment: run the script locally using psql

Comment: Also let's note that DBeaver has its own way of dealing with encoding, so you may want to track the encodings (file, client, DB)

Comment: Could you give an example of a script that works in DBeaver, but doesn't work in Liquibase? In plain text, as an update to your question.

Comment: @JGH this doesn't solve the problem as our destination is a lambda running in the cloud

Comment: @FrankHeikens I could solve this one script at a time but I'm looking for a solution that will help me track down an issue in *any* script that hits errors

Comment: @JGH encoding is a good idea